# Security architecture advice for non-web application

Tags: java, spring, security, architecture, spring-security

I am using Spring3.1 in a standalone env.

Although I am using Spring I am sure there could be other Java-ee frameworks(EJB,..) which I could adopt ideas from.

I am trying to build my security layer architecture and I would like to have a good idea by your experience how should I do so.

My application(non web application) is connected to an external protocol.

That protocol when you implement it is responsible for all the connection layer including login.

After a user login he can do certain commands like: subscribe, unsubscribe and so on..

When My app getting the login trigger I am auth the user via id agaisnt our database and then Via that protocol I response with reject or success messgae.

Afer success auth I can get from the user via the external protocol certain messages(subscribe, unsubscribe and so on..)

How should I wrap my app with the security layer ?

I thought about planning an aspect and create auth method for each method to double check that a user is really logged in?

how will I manage all logged in/non logged in users..

mybe the protocol layer(which I mention above) is enough for me?

Any ideas will be welcome.

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should take a look at http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/

Comment: i did but it seems they are more concentrating  on Web applications.

Comment: @rayman no, they're concentrating on SecurityContext, which is related to ThreadLocal. Spring Security is not dedicated to web only.

Comment: Could you be more specific with a dedicated link? Coz after I look at their examples I found only web concern security examples.

Comment: @rayman http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#tech-intro-authentication

Comment: Okie I read that. but honestly I need another reference it wasnt enough for me to understand the whole picture. what about method invocations security? what about make it as an aspect? how this service should run? I need a bit more:)

Comment: @rayman http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#authorization